# How can I create a Python CSV file after scraping information from a web page?

Tags: python, facebook, csv

I am writing a code (yes, I am new with this) to extract information from a page on facebook. I am using facebook-scraper to get the info. I need to create a CSV file to store this information, but I always come out empty.

Original code

```
from facebook_scraper import get_posts
for post in get_posts('bibliotecaunespbauru', pages=66):
    print(post['time']) # não funciona
    print(post['post_id'])
    print(post['text'])
    print(post['image'])
    print(post['video'])
    print(post['likes'])
    print(post['comments'])
    print(post['shares'])
    print(post['link'])
```

Code to store in the CSV file.

```
import csv
from facebook_scraper import get_posts
for post in get_posts('bibliotecaunespbauru', pages=10):
    data = [print(post['post_id']), print(post['text']), print(post['image'])]
with open("facebook.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
   writer = csv.writer(f)
   writer.writerow(data)
with open('facebook.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    for row in data:
        print(', '.join(row))
```

Hey, many thanks for this. it makes so much sense now. However, it still doesn't work as now it retrieves only one request, instead of 10 pages.

```
import csv
from facebook_scraper import get_posts
for post in get_posts('bibliotecaunespbauru', pages=10):
     data = [post['post_id'], post['text'], post['image']]
with open("facebook.csv", "a", newline="") as f:
   writer = csv.writer(f)
   writer.writerow(data)
with open('facebook.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    for row in data:
        print(', '.join(row))
```

Third attempt. Stil getting just one post.

```
import csv
from facebook_scraper import get_posts
for post in get_posts('bibliotecaunespbauru', pages=10):
     data = [post['post_id'], post['text'], post['image']]
with open("facebook.csv", "a", newline="") as f:
   writer = csv.writer(f)
   writer.writerow(data)
with open('facebook.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    for row in data:
        print(', '.join(row))
```

Fourth attempt.

```
import csv
from facebook_scraper import get_posts
for post in get_posts('bibliotecaunespbauru', pages=10):
    data = [post['post_id'], post['text'], post['image']]
    with open("facebook.csv", "a", newline="") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(data)
```

Returns

```
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-b4f7f9df1e02> in <module>
      5     with open("facebook.csv", "a", newline="") as f:
      6         writer = csv.writer(f)
----> 7         writer.writerow(data)

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\encodings\cp1252.py in encode(self, input, final)
     17 class IncrementalEncoder(codecs.IncrementalEncoder):
     18     def encode(self, input, final=False):
---> 19         return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
     20 
     21 class IncrementalDecoder(codecs.IncrementalDecoder):

UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 76-77: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: your code has indentation issues, read the comment in my answer, also dont edit the original question with solutions from answers, this can change the original question

Comment: Thanks! I still don't see it. I wrote the code again. Gonna update my question with your answer. I am not getting any error from indentation. The only problem now is just the number of posts retrived

Comment: just copy paste my entire code, I have run the code locally and I am getting different entries, the code you keep posting here is not the one I have given in the answer

Comment: Sorry, @python_learner! When I copied your code I got this here:

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-b4f7f9df1e02> in <module>
      5     with open("facebook.csv", "a", newline="") as f:
      6         writer = csv.writer(f)
----> 7         writer.writerow(data)

Comment: ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\encodings\cp1252.py in encode(self, input, final)
     17 class IncrementalEncoder(codecs.IncrementalEncoder):
     18     def encode(self, input, final=False):
---> 19         return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
     20 
     21 class IncrementalDecoder(codecs.IncrementalDecoder):

UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 76-77: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: ok, this is a different error, also can you re do all the edits you have done here? this is to make sure the questions stays true to its intent, future readers can read the comments to figure out what you had to go through

Comment: I am not getting that error, `('bibliotecaunespbauru', pages=10)` is this still the same?

Comment: Yes, thats correct

Comment: ok, I have run for `('bibliotecaunespbauru', pages=66)` and I dont get that error, are you sure you are using the code given below? I must be able to get the error you get

Comment: Yes! I changed it down to 10 just to test. Yes, same code. Let me try again. <may thanks for your patience, ou are too kind!

Comment: Same error. :( I have no idea now

Comment: use `open("facebook.csv", "a", newline="",encoding="utf-8")`

Comment: glad to know, it can be hard when you get started, also you can accept the answer if it helped 0:)

Comment: Hey, @python_learner. How can I accept your answer? =) I'd be glad t do it

Comment: you juts click the "tick" mark next to my answer, its in the same area where you upvote an answer, thanks :) happy coding

Comment: there you go! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues with your code.

The first problem is with how you create `data`

Wrong

`[print(post['post_id']), print(post['text']), print(post['image'])]`

Why

In this line you are printing as you get the values, the `return` value of a print is `None` and hence `None` is stored in the list.

Old Output of `data` at each iteration: `[None, None, None]`

Correction:

`[post['post_id'], post['text'], post['image']]`.

Output of new `data`: `['2092819824183367', 'Biblioteca da Unesp em Bauru ganha nova identidade visual ❤️\n\nhttps://youtu.be/dTCGp1eGmtM\n\nYOUTUBE.COM\nBiblioteca da Unesp em Bauru ganha nova identidade visual', None]`

(PS : idk what that translates to)

Second problem being the way you write to a file.

```
open("facebook.csv", "w", newline="")
```

Note the `a` in `open("facebook.csv", "a", newline="")` while writing to a file, this is used to open a file for opening a file in "append" mode, opening it in `w` mode (your old code) will overwrite the file at each loop, causing a new blank file at every loop and this behavior is not what you need.

So integrating all changes and indentation, this is a complete code for what you expect

```
import csv
from facebook_scraper import get_posts
for post in get_posts('bibliotecaunespbauru', pages=10):
    data = [post['post_id'], post['text'], post['image']]
    with open("facebook.csv", "a", newline="") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(data)
```

Regarding the unicode errors

you can use `open("facebook.csv", "a", newline="",encoding="utf-8")` when you open the file

Comment: Thank you! Now it is adding to another problem. It retrieves just one post from 10 pages.

Comment: did you try the code from here? your code had some indentation issues and I guess the one post that is saved is the last post?

Comment: yes! I did =) Thanks for the help. Now I am trying to solve another issue. It is only retrieving one  page